# apache benchmark: fails with lengthy custom header for authorization

Tags: apache, api, benchmarking, performance-testing

Apache benchmark is failing when using lengthy custom authorization header -

```
ab.exe -n 1 -c 1 -S -H "Authorization: SAML 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" -v 2 http://localhost:55495/rest/1
```

Please note that I am testing .net rest api which needs lengthy user token in authorization header to proceed.

Comment: downvoter, is there any reason to downvote? please make sure to comment before downvoting

Answer (score 3):

Apache Benchmark has a maximum request size of 2048 characters. Your header alone is more than 4KB in size, so that's why your test is failing. The maximum size of the request is given in `ab.c`. Look for `char _request[2048];` in that file and try increasing it. Note that the passed-in headers are also parsed into a header structure that may have limits as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can [install](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html#overview) the ab from [httpd source code](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi), which now sets `char _request[8192];`.
The code can be found in `httpd-2.4.53/support/ab.c`